# How do i align all these Read Mores in the same line in bootstrap

Tags: html, css

I'm making a menu but my "Read More"s are not aligned on the same line

https://i.gyazo.com/3a9dd4d8e497b3772110edd4ac35fa76.png

Here's the HTML code for it

```
<div class="home-menu parallax" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.5">
    <div class="container no-padding">
        <div class="hm-info">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <h3><span>Today Deals</span>Breakfast</h3>
                    <h4>Pancakes with Seasonal Fruit</h4>
                    <div class="menu-wrapper">
                        <p>Maple Syrup & Icecream</p>
                        <span class="price">$13.95</span>
                        <div class="dotted-bg"></div>
                    </div>
                    <h4>Pancakes with Maple Syrup</h4>
                    <div class="menu-wrapper">
                        <p>And Bacon</p>
                        <span class="price">$15.95</span>
                        <div class="dotted-bg"></div>
                    </div>
                    <h4>Smoked Salmon Omelette</h4>
                    <div class="menu-wrapper">
                        <p>with Onion, Capers and Toast</p>
                        <span class="price">$16.95</span>
                        <div class="dotted-bg"></div>
                    </div>
                    <h4>French Toast</h4>
                    <div class="menu-wrapper">
                        <p>with Maple Syrup</p>
                        <span class="price">$15.95</span>
                        <div class="dotted-bg"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="menureadmore">
                    <a href="#">Read More</a>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <h3><span>Today Deals</span>Coffee</h3>

                    <div class="menu-wrapper">
                        <span class="price">$12.00</span>
                        <h4>Cappucino</h4>
                    </div>

                    <div class="menu-wrapper">
                        <span class="price">$3.95</span>
                        <h4>Flat White</h4>
                    </div>

                    <div class="menu-wrapper">
                        <span class="price">$4.20</span>
                        <h4>Latte</h4>
                    </div>

                    <div class="menu-wrapper">
                        <span class="price">$4.80</span>
                        <h4>Chai Latte</h4>
                    </div>

                    <div class="menu-wrapper">
                        <span class="price">$4.40</span>
                        <h4>Hot Chocolate</h4>
                    </div>

                    <div class="menu-wrapper">
                        <span class="price">$4.55</span>
                        <h4>Hot Mocha</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="menureadmore" >
                    <a href="#">Read More</a>
                </div>
                </div>


                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <h3><span>Today Deals</span>Lunch</h3>

                    <h4>Beef Lasagne</h4>
                    <div class="menu-wrapper">
                        <p>With Salad</p>
                        <span class="price">$16.95</span>
                        <div class="dotted-bg"></div>
                    </div>

                    <h4>Fabulous Thai Chicken Patties</h4>
                    <div class="menu-wrapper">
                        <p>with Salad (Gluten Free)</p>
                        <span class="price">$15.95</span>
                        <div class="dotted-bg"></div>
                    </div>

                    <h4>Sensational Fillet Steak</h4>
                    <div class="menu-wrapper">
                        <p>Salad & Chips.</p>
                        <span class="price">$21.95</span>
                        <div class="dotted-bg"></div>
                    </div>

                    <h4>Roasted Vegetable Rosti Stack</h4>
                    <div class="menu-wrapper">
                        <p>(Gluten Free) with Salad</p>
                        <span class="price">$16.95</span>
                        <div class="dotted-bg"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="menureadmore">
                    <a href="#">Read More</a>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And CSS

```
.menu-wrapper .price 
  {
    float: right;
    padding-left: 10px;
    line-height: 19.8px;
    margin: 5px 0px;
    background: #f7f3e8;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #d80702;
    font-family: Lato;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 11;
  }
 .menureadmore{
    text-align:center;
        font-weight:700; 
    font-size: 16px;
  }
```

How do i align those "Read More"s so they are all aligned vertically?

Thanks

Comment: I think you should use min-height for all menu container..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap grid system is for row layouts and so the row that contains read more , that row should be enclosed in a div with class of row and then you can give them cols and they will align perfectly

Answer (score -1):

give position fix with bottom 0 or whatever you want (can also try with potion absolute)

Comment: It makes it stick to the bottom of the page not the div.
Should i do the absolute positioning on each one of those read mores seperately?

Will it still be responsive?

Comment: can give min-height to your parent div , po absolute to read more and also apply media query for responsive layout